# Looping an Array or List in C# and perform update using MongoDB

Tags: c#, arrays, list, request

i want to loop my request and perform something for my array ( Cart ) but i dont know how to loop the request

here is the request

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNMgf.png)

and here is the object class or the model for the request

```
 public class OrderRRModel
{
    public ObjectId id { get; set; }
    public string cutomer_name { get; set; }
    public string table_number { get; set; }
    public List<ListCart> Cart { get; set; }
    public OrderRRModel()
    {
        Cart = new List<ListCart>();
    }
}

public class ListCart
{
    public string product { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}
```

here is my full code

```
public ResponseModel<OrderRRModel> InsertOrderTest(string tokenAdmin, OrderRRModel entity)
    {
        var entityResult = new ResponseModel<OrderRRModel>();
        try
        {
            var auth = _adminCollection.Find(x => x.token == tokenAdmin).FirstOrDefault();
            if (auth != null)
            {
                var dates = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();

                // looping here
                var check = _menuCollection.Find(x => x.product_name == cart.product_name).FirstOrDefault();
                cart.price = check.price;

                var result = _menuCollection.UpdateOne(
                    x => x.product_name == cart.product_name,
                    Builders<MenuRRModel>.Update.Set(x => x.updated_at, dates)
                    .Set(x => x.stock, check.stock - cart.amount) // updating stock by reducing stock based on quantity
                    );
                // end of looping


                _orderCollection.InsertOne(entity);

                entityResult.Status = true;
                entityResult.Messages.Add(new ResponseMessageModel()
                {
                    Type = ResponseMessageModel.MessageType.SUCCESS,
                    Title = "Success",
                    Message = "Successful"
                });
            }
            else
            {
                entityResult.Messages.Add(new ResponseMessageModel()
                {
                    Type = ResponseMessageModel.MessageType.WARNING,
                    Title = "Action Failed",
                    Message = "Anda Tidak Memiliki Wewenang!"
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            entityResult.Messages.Add(new ResponseMessageModel()
            {
                Type = ResponseMessageModel.MessageType.ERROR,
                Title = "Error",
                Message = ex.Message
            });
        }
        return entityResult;
    }
```

can you guys tell me the code for looping my request ?
please be kind im a newbie

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
foreach (var cart in entity.cart)
                {
                    cart.itemcart
                }
```